# Extend a list with numbers that match initial bias

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, pandas

I have a list that essentially goes as such:

```
Dalc = [1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,2.......]
```

It currently contains 395 elements, and I'm trying to extend it such that I keep the same percentage of 1's, 2's, 3's, 4's and 5's. Min = 1, Max = 5, and I initially did the following to try and extend the list past 10000 elements:

```
from random import randint

....

Dalc_add = []
dalc_max = max(Dalc)
dalc_min = min(Dalc)
i = 0

while i < 10000:
    Dalc_add.append(randint(dalc_min, dalc_max))
    i = i + 1

Dalc.append(Dalc_add)
```

What this gave was a list with the initial bias present for the first 395 iterations, but then after that the rest of the list looked like:

`[1,5,3,2,3,1,4,2,4,5,2,5,3,2,1,3,4,2,1,3,3,4,1........]`

A lot more 3, 4, & 5 present, and it completely messes up any statistical analysis I can perform.

How do I extend the list as above, while also preserving the weights and biases present (with respect to frequency of occurrence) for the list values?

Comment: Sounds like you want [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) with weights.

Comment: if you have numpy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I'm looking through the random.choices docs, but still a little confused where the weights are _set_, Could you explain that a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). This randomly samples from the original list. If you feed it the original list, you don't need to use weights:

```
import numpy as np

Dalc = [1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,2]
new_choices = np.random.choice(Dalc, size=10000)
Dalc += list(new_choices)
```

Comment: You don't need numpy for this, you can just use `import random` and then `random.choice(Dalc)`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

```
from random import choices
Dalc.extend(choices(Dalc, k=numTimes))
```

or

```
from numpy.random import choice
Dalc.extend(choice(Dalc, size=numTimes))
```

This chooses randomly from `Dalc` `numTimes` times, which should obviously keep your weights the same.

Which you should use depends on two things, whether `numTimes` is large and whether `Dalc` is large. Using `timeit`:

```
import timeit

print('Standard | Numpy')

print(timeit.timeit('choices([1,2,3,4,5], k=10000)', setup='from random import choices', number=10000), end=' | ')
print(timeit.timeit('choice([1,2,3,4,5], size=10000)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=10000))

print(timeit.timeit('choices([1,2,3,4,5], k=1000)', setup='from random import choices', number=10000), end=' | ')
print(timeit.timeit('choice([1,2,3,4,5], size=1000)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=10000))

print(timeit.timeit('choices([1,2,3,4,5], k=100)', setup='from random import choices', number=10000), end=' | ')
print(timeit.timeit('choice([1,2,3,4,5], size=100)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=10000))

print(timeit.timeit('choices([1,2,3,4,5], k=10)', setup='from random import choices', number=10000), end=' | ')
print(timeit.timeit('choice([1,2,3,4,5], size=10)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=10000))

print(timeit.timeit('choices([1,2,3,4,5], k=5)', setup='from random import choices', number=10000), end=' | ')
print(timeit.timeit('choice([1,2,3,4,5], size=5)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=10000))

print()

print(timeit.timeit('choices([1,2,3,4,5]*10000, k=60)', setup='from random import choices', number=10000), end=' | ')
print(timeit.timeit('choice([1,2,3,4,5]*10000, size=60)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=10000))

print(timeit.timeit('choices([1,2,3,4,5]*1000, k=60)', setup='from random import choices', number=10000), end=' | ')
print(timeit.timeit('choice([1,2,3,4,5]*1000, size=60)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=10000))

print(timeit.timeit('choices([1,2,3,4,5]*100, k=60)', setup='from random import choices', number=10000), end=' | ')
print(timeit.timeit('choice([1,2,3,4,5]*100, size=60)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=10000))

print(timeit.timeit('choices([1,2,3,4,5]*10, k=60)', setup='from random import choices', number=10000), end=' | ')
print(timeit.timeit('choice([1,2,3,4,5]*10, size=60)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=10000))

print(timeit.timeit('choices([1,2,3,4,5], k=60)', setup='from random import choices', number=10000), end=' | ')
print(timeit.timeit('choice([1,2,3,4,5], size=60)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=10000))
```

Giving us the output:

```
Standard | Numpy
25.372834796129872 | 1.8409739351390613
2.5144703081718696 | 0.316072358469512
0.2527455696737988 | 0.15912525398981003
0.03453532081119093 | 0.13720956183202304
0.021838018317897223 | 0.1544090297115197

1.2724984282899072 | 26.585005448108767
0.29600333450513006 | 2.7196871458182343
0.16926004909861803 | 0.4086584816186516
0.14861485298857957 | 0.16870138091688602
0.15621485532244606 | 0.1448146694886887
```

So if numTimes is quite large, Numpy is the clear winner, but if the size of `Dalc` is quite large it seems that vanilla python is the way to go.